# Windows - Writing to file with `.txt` or `.zip` says Access denied

Tags: windows

I'm trying to write data to a text file in Windows programatically (either through `cmd` directly or from a scripting language like Lua), but if I try to open any file with the following conditions, an error occurs, saying permission denied.

- the file name ends with `.txt` or `.zip`
- I try to create the file inside some subfolders of my user folder, e.g. `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\**\file.txt` or `%USERPROFILE%\Pictures\**\file.zip`.
- this is done programatically (works fine using any GUI).

This happens only on Windows, and even if I run `cmd` with admin rights.

```
C:\Users\Username\Pictures>echo aaaa > a.txt
Access denied.
C:\Users\Username\Documents>echo aaaa > a.txt
Access denied.
```

EDIT: I noticed this was specific to subfolders of `%USERPROFILE%`, and not related to Lua, which the original text of this question was about. So I rewrote the question to reflect the problem properly.

I still can't find any pattern of which folders are affected by this, currently only Pictures and Documents.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem without Lua? Can you run in command line window `echo TEST > aaa.txt` ?

Comment: This runs just fine, the error only happens with Lua.

Comment: Does run-as-admin help?

Comment: Even with admin rights, it still errors out in Lua

Comment: Does this happen only in system folders?  In other words, try to create regular folder `Test` inside "My Documents" of the current user and run Lua script inside `Test`.

Comment: What about files with random name and extension such as `q2w3e.n7m` or just name `q2w3e`?

Comment: Is it your own computer?  Or is this computer part of a corporate network managed by admin at your work?

Comment: It's in an arbitrary folder inside my Documents folder, in my own computer. Currently, I only noticed this happening with `.txt` and `.zip`. If I use a random extension, it works fine.

Comment: Since this question is about Windows, not about programming, it might be more suitable for superuser.com